# Microsoft Teams Powershell command not found in cmdlet if running a script

Tags: powershell

I want to user a powershell script but always getting the error, that the name isn't part of a cmdlet (New-CsOnlineApplicationInstance). If I don't use the script, it works fine. Anyone which can help me?

```
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams

#Store the data from AddingUser.csv in the $users variable
$users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\01_Data\Powershell\addinguser.csv"

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $userCredential

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $users) {

    $account        = $User.account
    $displayname    = $User.displayname
    
    #CallQueue will be created from the CSV file
    New-CsOnlineApplicationInstance -UserPrincipalName $account -ApplicationId 11cd3e2e-fccb-42ad-ad00-878b93575e07 -DisplayName "$displayname"
    
    }

Disconnect-MicrosoftTeams
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: The [New-CsOnlineApplicationInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/new-csonlineapplicationinstance?view=skype-ps) cmdlet is part of the SkypeForBusiness module...